# Javascript - Every link should be open in popup

Tags: javascript, href

Open Any wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). 
If user click on any link (href), that link should not be open as next window. Link should be open in a popup.

I have already open in a popup window as mention below

```
var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i=0; i < allAnchors.length; i++) {
    var element = allAnchors[i];
    element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let aref = this.getAttribute("href");
    window.open(aref,'_blank','width=900,height=300');
  }.bind(element));
}
```

But I want to open in popup.

Comment: Well that's not how it currently works so what is your question?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't (Chrome on Windows)

Comment: You can probably do this by injecting some script into the page that adds an onclick hander to all a tags with an href, and calls window.open then cancels the default link follow.

Comment: I just want to know that how can we load every href in popup

Comment: @Rup can you help on this,?

Comment: You will need to write  userscript to put in a user script extension like Tampermonkey or write your own extension. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: Honestly, most browsers are just gonna reject such requests.

Comment: "I have already open in a popup window" - great, looks like that works to me! When you say "But I want to open in popup" what's the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

You can't tell a browser to specifically open a link in a new window, however the above will open all links (loaded into the document at the time of running the above code) in a new tab or window when clicked, depending on the browser configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a link in a popup,
use some library or framework like angularjs to open the content in pop up (use $md-dialog in angular)

Comment: can't use angular I've to use javascript only